# stripe fund transfer not working properly

Tags: php

I am creating e-Com website. In which I am using stripe payment. The goal is we charge the user and then send amount to admin account and 80% of total charge transfer into vendor account.

The user payment working fine. In stripe admin account i can see the amount is increases per transaction. And vendor amount transfer is also working fine. In stripe admin account ,The Transfer link on left side showing all transfer history.

But when i login to vendor stripe account , I am getting $0 amount. Because transfer was not done.

Here is my transfer code:

```
 $transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(                 
                   "currency" => "usd",
                  "recipient" => "rp_16lDd5AjH6fE1nozBz8hoQMY",
                  'amount' => $amount,
                  //'destination' => "ba_16lDe5AjH6fE1noz5V8oSTzU",
                  'destination' => "ba_16nn5nAjH6fE1nozX6xpp6JA",
                  "failure_message" => null,
                  "failure_code" => null,
                  )
                );
```

It gives me success msg. After 2-7 days transfer amount not transferred into vendor stripe account. Please help me out.